# Referencing an element from a function attached to it using .data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom

I can attach a function to an element using `.data()`, but how can I access the element the function is stored in, inside the function?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to the element inside the function when you define it. Then it'll be available when the function is run.

Comment: this might be the right answer, but I don't know if you could do something similar to `$(this)` to get at the element in the function body...

Comment: You can't, which is why I did not suggest it.

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 4 minutes! Thanks. Also - am I right in thinking that there's actually no problem with circular references because the reference won't be stored on the element itself?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that is correct. I won't stake my life on it, though.